# Recover from OpenCL freeze in Linux

Tags: linux, graphics, opencl, recovery

I am writing my first OpenCL kernels on an Ubuntu machine with an NVIDIA card. Once in a while, the application totally freezes the whole computer. The mouse does not move, and the only way to reboot is by force-pressing the power button.

I've realized that the reason for the freezes is that I accidentally read past the last index of a global, read-only float array. While this is something I don't intend to do often, it might still happen in the future.

My question is - is there any way to prevent the computer from **completely** shutting down if this happens again? I know that, for example, Windows can shut down bad GLSL kernels and recover with a graphics driver restart. Is something similar possible here?

Comment: That's a good question.  My solution is to always run my kernels on the CPU first.  They never crash the whole system.  Once the kernel is stable on the CPU I try it on the GPU.  Also you can use printf on the CPU which I find very useful for debugging.

Comment: Windows uses timeout detection and recovery (TDR) to try to restart the graphics driver once it has frozen.  No idea if Linux has something similar.  Does the keyboard still work?  There used to be a key combination for switching between consoles.  Not an ideal solution but perhaps it would allow you to properly shutdown the PC.  Remember that the display driver has frozen, hence the mouse does not move but all your apps are still running in the background - their progress isn't being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to completely recover but you can recover better using SysRq (sometimes called System Request or Magic SysRq). By executing a specific key combination you can have Linux reboot in some what of a sane way (killing processes and unmounting filesystems). This key sequence is described in detail at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key so I won't repeat it here.

In some cases you might be able to still SSH to the device. If this is your case you might be in more luck. If you can SSH there are a number of other options you can try such as: unloading/reloading the crashed module, restarting the xserver, or at least rebooting the normal way.

Although I'm not an expert on "HURD" I believe it was designed to handle this type of condition better. The only other solution I can think of is using two graphics cards one for X and one for OpenCL. Dependidng on what you are doing you might have to passthrough the NVIDIA to a VM in order to completely isolate it off your host.